# How can I upgrade python3 to python3.6 or higher in xenial?

Tags: ubuntu, python3

The max version of python in xenial apt repository is 3.5.1-3

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.5.1-3).
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

But I want to be able to use python3.6 or above.

How can I upgrade it via apt?

Comment: if you're willing to use a PPA repository, there's instructions at [How to Install Python 3.6.1 in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/)

Comment: @cas Who the heck is Jonathan and why would I trust him ? I know very little about PPAs but it looks like this is using some random guy's code as my Python source?